# my simple jquery validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Hey guys here is my code:

```
 <script>$('td#view-details').click(function() {
     var fg = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();     
     $('#'+fg+'confirm').click(function () {
         if($('form #' + fg + 'input[name=test]').val() == "") {
             $('#error_notification').fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
             return false;
         } else {
             $(main).text('show');
             $('#' + fg).addClass('details').removeClass('active');
             $('#success_notification').fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
         }
     });
</script>
<html>
    <table width="742" id="redemptions_landing_page" valign="top">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Investor Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Credit</th>
            <th>Request Amount</th>
            <th>Request Mode</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1848719408</td>
            <td>arvind</td>
            <td>xxxyy@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Rs 5000</td>
            <td>Rs 300</td>
            <td>Cheque</td>
            <td id="view-details">show</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form  id="1848719408">
        <textarea cols="40" rows="10" id="remarks" placeholder="Remarks (enter courier number and courier service provider for confirmed redemptions, enter reason for rejected redemptions)"></textarea>
    <h3 class="bbrdt">Redemption Amount</h3>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="Amount_For_Investor" placeholder="Amount For Investor" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="test" type="text" id="courier_charges" placeholder="Courier Charges"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input value="Confirm" type="button" id="1848719408confirm" />
<button id="reject">Reject</button></form>
```

I want to validate the text fields but it's not working, the success notification is showing again when the text fields are empty, but the error notification is not displaying.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but you have a very wrong `html` tag where it should be `body` or `div`.

Comment: i already added the document ready function in local i forgot to put here sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always wrap your code in the [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure the DOM has loaded, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td#view-details').click(function() {
    var fg = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();
    $('#' + fg + 'confirm').click(function() {
        if ($('form #' + fg + 'input[name=test]').val() == "") {
            $('#error_notification').fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(main).text('show');
            $('#' + fg).addClass('details').removeClass('active');
            $('#success_notification').fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the document ready. At the moment you are binding the `click` event, the element does not yet exists.

Try this

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    // Your code go's here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Niels pointed out, you should wait for the document to be ready before starting anything, because you're trying to access some things that are not yet created.

You should try this instead:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     // Your code
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree it is good practice to wrap in a document ready I do not think that is your problem.

```
<script>
$('td#view-details').click(function() {
var fg = $(this).parent().find(":first-child").text();
$('#' + fg + ' confirm').click(function() {
    if ($('form #' + fg + ' input[name=test]').val() == "") {
        $('#error_notification').fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $(main).text('show');
        $('#' + fg).addClass('details').removeClass('active');
        $('#success_notification').fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
    }
});
</script>
```

var fg = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text(); // this line changed to
var fg = $(this).parent().find(":first-child").text();

$('#' + fg + 'confirm').click(function() { // this line was missing a space for confirm

if ($('form #' + fg + 'input[name=test]').val() == "") { // this line was missing space for input

Hope this helps!

Comment: without those spaces your selector would look like:

Comment: $('#1848719408confirm') which makes no sense

Comment: $('form #1848719408input[name=test]')

Comment: notice how there is no spce between the ID text and the selector your looking for